# socket.io basic emit and listener failing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io

I have an App I have inherited which has socket IO working already on a number of events. It's a game that moves pieces on a board and has notation recording the moves. I'm building the notation.

Im trying to create a new emitter/listener pair for the notation, but it fails.

I have the emitter in one file as part of a function which already uses the two objects I need to pass (at the time/context I need to pass them)...

```
function writeMoveLog(game,moveInfo){
    socket.emit('notation', {game: game, moveInfo: moveInfo});

    (...rest of the function which works ok)
```

and my listener is simply this in the main js file...

```
    socket.on('notation', function(gameState){
        writeMoveLog(gameState.game, gameState.moveInfo);    
    });
```

Basically I'm trying to throw those two objects to the other client end of the socket and have it trigger the function as well, updating the notation. Both clients use the same files.

I'm using the the same basic pattern as the pre-existing 'move' event which works fine - an un-named object passed by the emit, then named and used at the on/listener - these are both in the same main js file.

```
    socket.emit('move', {
       mInfo: result.mInfo,
       mResult: result,
       senString: gameGen.saveToSEN(game),
       mGame: {contents : game}, //I added this, it works
    });

    socket.on('move', function (move) {
        game = gameGen.loadFromSEN(move.senString);
        gui.draw(game.board);
        etc etc
```

I'm not getting anything at all in the debugger, no 'notation' event whatsoever, and yet I can easily see the 'move' event contents going back and forth. I've tried using that event, but it doesn't have the objects I need in that context (moveInfo entirely, and game seems missing detail I need).

I'm using Chrome Dev tools for my main dev env, and Firefox for the other connected client.

What gives? Do I need to register the event somehow somewhere else? I can't see that that has been done with the 'move' event, I thought all I needed to do was make the call and configure the listener, and whichever client is making the move will be the server for the 'notation' event.

On a side note, the Chrome Dev breakpoints don't seem to work as expected when I'm debugging socket.io stuff - is this normal? Why can't I make a breakpoint within a socket.emit so I can investigate the objects which are available in that context, like I can with other functions?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with code make sure you have included socket.js script in front end where you listening and also check wethere your event is not collides.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - can you elaborate about events not "colliding"? 

What happens if you have two emit statements for the same event, or two listeners for that matter - does it have to be one-to-one, i.e. only one emit and one on statement per page/app? They're basically a single page app - using gulp concatenation to make distribution files, which are then loaded by the html page. There is also some Angular stuff at play.

One other thought - when changing socket.io server and clients events in the code, do I need go so far as to restart node to see the changes?

Comment: Sorry for late reply , collision means should event duplication I think it's not an issue. I have implemented sample short script using nodejs, socket.io here https://github.com/ashishtiwari1993/polling_counter. May be this can help you.

Comment: ok, that all makes sense to me, there's nothing there that I seem to have missed. 

I tried this in my app - in the **same place** as the existing working socket.emit('move' etc)   I duplicated it and simply renamed it from socket.emit('move', ... to socket.emit('notation'. I duplicated the socket.on as well and commented out all the function calls. 

Save, rebuild dist file, restart browsers, relogin, new game and play - and I **still** only see the move event fire, but **not** the notation event, even though they are **exactly the same** in all but event name... WTF?